# Is there a way to give a content_panel a "tagselect" style?

Tags: wagtail, django-taggit, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-snippet

Is there a way to give a content_panel a "tagselect" style so that snippet choosing is as convenient as tag choosing? I need the "create new" functionality to be able to take more fields besides title (like a web link and a picture affiliated with a tag)

Comment: Perhaps [wagtail-autocomplete](https://wagtail-autocomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is something close to what you're looking for?

Comment: @gasman brilliant suggestion that would answer the question without the recent edit (it does provide autocomplete but docs don't describe a process of creating multiple-field tags)

Comment: or... I'll play with it and let you know. In any case, post this as an answer, not a comment, I'd love to give you points.